# Windows 10 - How do I unlock lock screen by pressing any key like Windows 8/8.1?

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-10, lock-screen

#### Having a single (local) user with no password

- In **Windows 8/8.1**, I could unlock the screen by pressing any key.
- In **Windows 10**, I first see the "background" lockscreen (the one that has a configurable background and shows the time) which I can dismiss using any key.
  But right after that I see a "Sign in" screen where I have to press the "Sign in" button (Using mouse, or <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

How can I skip the second screen (the "Sign in" screen) and just have the one that I can dismiss using any key?
Or just skip the second using any key?

I've tried to disable lock screen using Group Policy Editor and Registry, and User Account settings (netplwiz.exe).

It just disabled the first screen, so I have the "Sign in" screen which I can bypass now using just <kbd>Enter</kbd> because it's focused already, yet I prefer unlocking using any key, and moreover I prefer to see only the first screen as it is nicer and more informative.